F4 not working on Yoga 7
I bought the Lenovo Yoga Pro 7 with the AMD processor, and installed Fedora on it. For now, it runs smoothly: the only problem I noticed is that, although all keyboard keys and combinations work, the F4 button (that activates and mutes the microphone, and it has also a LED) doesn't work at all. It isn't detected if I go on keyboard shortcut and I try to bind it to the mic. The Fn+F4 combination, instead, works, and is detected correctly as F4 (because I don't have fnlock on). Also, other LED buttons seem to work fine.
What can I do?
